# Lavel 5.6.8 Eloquent: many to many + many to one pluck method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Database structure

**users**

- id
- username
- password

**cityareas**

- id
- name
- area_id

**cityarea_user**

- id
- cityarea_id
- user_id

**areas**

- id
- name

I have also models where relationships are add.

**User**

```
public function cityareas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cityarea');
}
```

**Cityarea**

```
public function area()

    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
    }

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User');
}
```

**Area**

```
public function cityareas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cityarea');
}
```

**QUESTION:**
How I can get list (I try with pluck) on areas where user belongs?

I try it make this:

```
$users = User::with('cityareas.area')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Result is something like that

[image]

Then I try to pluck there only area.id or area.name or both but not working...
What is best way to do this?

Comment: add ur pluck code too

Comment: what is your required output?

Comment: Why don't you do `Areas::with([ 'cityareas.user' => function ($q) use ($id) { $q->where('id', $id); }])->get()` instead ? (not sure on how you named the relationships but the point is you need to go via the area)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $users = User::with(['cityareas' => function($query){
          $query->with(['area' => function( $q){
    });

    })->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Try like this and use Closure inside it.

Hope this helps